# Match to return all values instead of just first in a column

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to find all the cells that have the value 21 in the column AGE. I currently have the following formula which works fine with returning just the first TRUE value:

```
=MATCH(21,AGE,0)
```

However, it does not continue through the whole column to return the rest of the results. Any help will be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use AGGREGATE like this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B$2:$B$7)/($B$2:$B$7=21),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

as it is dragged/copied down it will get the next in the line, until it finds no more, then it will fill the cell with `""`.

[image]